# Javascript getElementsByTagName broken firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I'm getting the weirdest issues with Javascript in Firefox today.

I'm trying to manipulate some table rows, but `.getElementsByTagName("tr");` is pulling back junk.

```
dynamicTable.tableBody = dynamicTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var tableRows = dynamicTable.tableBody.getElementsByTagName("TR");
var actualTableRows = new Array();
for(var i in tableRows) {
    var row = tableRows[i];
    alert(row.tagName);
    if(row.tagName == "TR"){
       actualTableRows.push(row);
    }
}
dynamicTable.bodyRows = actualTableRows;
```

The puzzling part of course is my temporary hack to fix the error. For some reason `.getElementsByTagName("tr")` is pulling back some functions also.

Incidently, the alert above goes something like this "TR TR TR TR undefined undefined undefined".

The code I wanted was something like this

```
dynamicTable.bodyRows = dynamicTable.tableBody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

But then `bodyrows` does not contain just `<tr>` elements, it has the aforementioned junk in it.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** If I just use the second block of code, I get a list 24 elements long on a table that has 21 table rows (tr elements) . The first block of code is just a hack that fixes the problem.

If I change the alert to `alert(row)` I get:

```
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
...

function item() {
    [native code]
}

21

function namedItem() {
    [native code]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `for-in` statement is enumerating also the `item` and `namedItem` methods present on the [HTMLCollection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506) that `getElementsByTagName` returns.

To **iterate** over array-like elements like DOM Collections, a simple sequential loop is always recommend, the `for...in` statement is meant to be used to **enumerate** object properties.

```
dynamicTable.tableBody = dynamicTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var tableRows = dynamicTable.tableBody.getElementsByTagName("TR");
var actualTableRows = new Array();
for(var i = 0, n = tableRows.length; i < n; i++) { // <---- simple for loop
    var row = tableRows[i];
    alert(row.tagName);
    if(row.tagName == "TR"){
       actualTableRows.push(row);
    }
}
dynamicTable.bodyRows = actualTableRows;
```

You shouldn't use `for..in` with array-like objects because:

- The order of iteration is not guaranteed, the array indexes may not visited in the numeric order.
- Inherited properties are also enumerated (This can be another source of problems).

Recommended article:

- [Enumeration VS Iteration](http://dhtmlkitchen.com/?category=/JavaScript/&date=2007/10/21/&entry=Iteration-Enumeration-Primitives-and-Objects)

Comment: The enumeration is not the problem the problem exists before the enumeration happens

Comment: @Sheldon, `for-in` enumerates also over the `item` and `namedItem` methods of [HTMLCollections](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506)

Comment: Ah, that was the problem in another unposted block of code, I enumerated over it then and it pulled back all the properties of tableRows not just the actual entries. I assumed the .getElementsByTagName was pulling back too many things.